# Modifying VB.Net program that uses normal ping method to use Async ping method

Tags: vb.net, asynchronous, ping

I have created a program which acts as both a simple local area network map, but also as a troubleshooting program for pinpointing faults (ie. determining where a connection might be broken). There is a main screen that looks like this:

[Image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6yo9n.jpg)

and each button links to subscreens, such as this:

[Image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5cINn.jpg)

The program works well enough as is, but using the normal ping method it requires each ping to finish before sending the next one and can sometimes freeze up the program for several seconds while it waits for a response (especially in situations where multiple pings fail and a large amount of devices are being pinged, as in the second image).

Currently the way I am doing this is by fairly simple programming in which I ping each device based on a list in a .ini file and then update it's associated button backcolor and labels (one label for the Response time, and one to keep track of how many times the ping request fails). Here is a sample of my code:

```
Dim INI_File As New IniFile(My.Application.Info.DirectoryPath + "/IPAddresses.ini")

Public Sub pingallmills()
    Dim MyPing As New System.Net.NetworkInformation.Ping


    Dim MyEMillPing As System.Net.NetworkInformation.PingReply = MyPing.Send(INI_File.GetString("Main Screen", "E-Mill", "(none)"), 200)
    Label4.Text = INI_File.GetString("Main Screen", "E-Mill", "(none)")
    If MyEMillPing.Status = Net.NetworkInformation.IPStatus.Success Then
        Button1.BackColor = Color.LightGreen
        Label2.Text = MyEMillPing.RoundtripTime & " ms"
    Else
        Button1.BackColor = Color.LightSalmon
        Label100.Text = Label100.Text + 1
    End If

    Dim MyAMillPing As System.Net.NetworkInformation.PingReply = MyPing.Send(INI_File.GetString("Main Screen", "A-Mill", "(none)"), 200)
    Label5.Text = INI_File.GetString("Main Screen", "A-Mill", "(none)")
    If MyAMillPing.Status = Net.NetworkInformation.IPStatus.Success Then
        Button2.BackColor = Color.LightGreen
        Label7.Text = MyAMillPing.RoundtripTime & " ms"
    Else
        Button2.BackColor = Color.LightSalmon
        Label98.Text = Label98.Text + 1
    End If

    Dim MyCMillPing As System.Net.NetworkInformation.PingReply = MyPing.Send(INI_File.GetString("Main Screen", "C-Mill", "(none)"), 400)
    Label9.Text = INI_File.GetString("Main Screen", "C-Mill", "(none)")
    If MyCMillPing.Status = Net.NetworkInformation.IPStatus.Success Then
        Button3.BackColor = Color.LightGreen
        Label11.Text = MyCMillPing.RoundtripTime & " ms"
    Else
        Button3.BackColor = Color.LightSalmon
        Label96.Text = Label96.Text + 1
    End If

    Dim MyAtoCPing As System.Net.NetworkInformation.PingReply = MyPing.Send(INI_File.GetString("Main Screen", "AtoC", "(none)"), 200)
    Label14.Text = INI_File.GetString("Main Screen", "AtoC", "(none)")
    If MyAtoCPing.Status = Net.NetworkInformation.IPStatus.Success Then
        Panel1.BackColor = Color.LightBlue
        Label16.Text = MyAtoCPing.RoundtripTime & " ms"
    Else
        Panel1.BackColor = Color.LightSalmon
        Label102.Text = Label102.Text + 1
    End If

    Dim MyCtoAPing As System.Net.NetworkInformation.PingReply = MyPing.Send(INI_File.GetString("Main Screen", "CtoA", "(none)"), 200)
    Label20.Text = INI_File.GetString("Main Screen", "CtoA", "(none)")
    If MyCtoAPing.Status = Net.NetworkInformation.IPStatus.Success Then
        Panel2.BackColor = Color.LightBlue
        Label22.Text = MyCtoAPing.RoundtripTime & " ms"
    Else
        Panel2.BackColor = Color.LightSalmon
        Label104.Text = Label104.Text + 1
    End If

    Dim MyAOfficesPing As System.Net.NetworkInformation.PingReply = MyPing.Send(INI_File.GetString("Main Screen", "AOffices", "(none)"), 400)
    Label18.Text = INI_File.GetString("Main Screen", "AOffices", "(none)")
    If MyAOfficesPing.Status = Net.NetworkInformation.IPStatus.Success Then
        Button4.BackColor = Color.LightGreen
        Label25.Text = MyAOfficesPing.RoundtripTime & " ms"
    Else
        Button4.BackColor = Color.LightSalmon
        Label94.Text = Label94.Text + 1
    End If

    Dim MyCtoFabPing As System.Net.NetworkInformation.PingReply = MyPing.Send(INI_File.GetString("Main Screen", "CtoFab", "(none)"), 200)
    Label28.Text = INI_File.GetString("Main Screen", "CtoFab", "(none)")
    If MyCtoFabPing.Status = Net.NetworkInformation.IPStatus.Success Then
        Panel3.BackColor = Color.LightBlue
        Label30.Text = MyCtoFabPing.RoundtripTime & " ms"
    Else
        Panel3.BackColor = Color.LightSalmon
        Label106.Text = Label106.Text + 1
    End If

    Dim MyFabtoCPing As System.Net.NetworkInformation.PingReply = MyPing.Send(INI_File.GetString("Main Screen", "FabtoC", "(none)"), 200)
    Label33.Text = INI_File.GetString("Main Screen", "FabtoC", "(none)")
    If MyFabtoCPing.Status = Net.NetworkInformation.IPStatus.Success Then
        Panel4.BackColor = Color.LightBlue
        Label35.Text = MyFabtoCPing.RoundtripTime & " ms"
    Else
        Panel4.BackColor = Color.LightSalmon
        Label49.Text = Label49.Text + 1
    End If

    Dim MyFabshopPing As System.Net.NetworkInformation.PingReply = MyPing.Send(INI_File.GetString("Main Screen", "FabShop", "(none)"), 400)
    Label37.Text = INI_File.GetString("Main Screen", "Fabshop", "(none)")
    If MyFabshopPing.Status = Net.NetworkInformation.IPStatus.Success Then
        Button7.BackColor = Color.LightGreen
        Label39.Text = MyFabshopPing.RoundtripTime & " ms"
    Else
        Button7.BackColor = Color.LightSalmon
        Label45.Text = Label45.Text + 1
    End If

    Dim MyElecShopPing As System.Net.NetworkInformation.PingReply = MyPing.Send(INI_File.GetString("Main Screen", "ElecShop", "(none)"), 400)
    Label51.Text = INI_File.GetString("Main Screen", "ElecShop", "(none)")
    If MyElecShopPing.Status = Net.NetworkInformation.IPStatus.Success Then
        Button6.BackColor = Color.LightGreen
        Label53.Text = MyElecShopPing.RoundtripTime & " ms"
    Else
        Button6.BackColor = Color.LightSalmon
        Label47.Text = Label47.Text + 1
    End If

    Dim MySMillPing As System.Net.NetworkInformation.PingReply = MyPing.Send(INI_File.GetString("Main Screen", "S-Mill", "(none)"), 200)
    Label59.Text = INI_File.GetString("Main Screen", "S-Mill", "(none)")
    If MySMillPing.Status = Net.NetworkInformation.IPStatus.Success Then
        Button8.BackColor = Color.LightGreen
        Label61.Text = MySMillPing.RoundtripTime & " ms"
    Else
        Button8.BackColor = Color.LightSalmon
        Label55.Text = Label55.Text + 1
    End If

    Dim MyContainerPing As System.Net.NetworkInformation.PingReply = MyPing.Send(INI_File.GetString("Main Screen", "Container", "(none)"), 200)
    Label71.Text = INI_File.GetString("Main Screen", "Container", "(none)")
    If MyContainerPing.Status = Net.NetworkInformation.IPStatus.Success Then
        Button10.BackColor = Color.LightGreen
        Label73.Text = MyContainerPing.RoundtripTime & " ms"
    Else
        Button10.BackColor = Color.LightSalmon
        Label43.Text = Label43.Text + 1
    End If

    Dim MyDMillOfficesPing As System.Net.NetworkInformation.PingReply = MyPing.Send(INI_File.GetString("Main Screen", "DOffices", "(none)"), 200)
    Label67.Text = INI_File.GetString("Main Screen", "DOffices", "(none)")
    If MyDMillOfficesPing.Status = Net.NetworkInformation.IPStatus.Success Then
        Button9.BackColor = Color.LightGreen
        Label69.Text = MyDMillOfficesPing.RoundtripTime & " ms"
    Else
        Button9.BackColor = Color.LightSalmon
        Label57.Text = Label57.Text + 1
    End If

    Dim MyDMillPing As System.Net.NetworkInformation.PingReply = MyPing.Send(INI_File.GetString("Main Screen", "D-Mill", "(none)"), 400)
    Label75.Text = INI_File.GetString("Main Screen", "D-Mill", "(none)")
    If MyDMillPing.Status = Net.NetworkInformation.IPStatus.Success Then
        Button11.BackColor = Color.LightGreen
        Label77.Text = MyDMillPing.RoundtripTime & " ms"
    Else
        Button11.BackColor = Color.LightSalmon
        Label92.Text = Label92.Text + 1
    End If

    Dim MyServerRoomPing As System.Net.NetworkInformation.PingReply = MyPing.Send(INI_File.GetString("Main Screen", "ServerRoom", "(none)"), 200)
    Label87.Text = INI_File.GetString("Main Screen", "ServerRoom", "(none)")
    If MyServerRoomPing.Status = Net.NetworkInformation.IPStatus.Success Then
        Button12.BackColor = Color.LightGreen
        Label89.Text = MyServerRoomPing.RoundtripTime & " ms"
    Else
        Button12.BackColor = Color.LightSalmon
        Label42.Text = Label42.Text + 1
    End If

    Dim MyMechanicShopPing As System.Net.NetworkInformation.PingReply = MyPing.Send(INI_File.GetString("Main Screen", "MechanicShop", "(none)"), 200)
    Label114.Text = INI_File.GetString("Main Screen", "MechanicShop", "(none)")
    If MyMechanicShopPing.Status = Net.NetworkInformation.IPStatus.Success Then
        Button13.BackColor = Color.LightGreen
        Label116.Text = MyMechanicShopPing.RoundtripTime & " ms"
    Else
        Button13.BackColor = Color.LightSalmon
        Label111.Text = Label111.Text + 1
    End If

    Dim MyFuelStationPing As System.Net.NetworkInformation.PingReply = MyPing.Send(INI_File.GetString("Main Screen", "FuelStation", "(none)"), 200)
    Label227.Text = INI_File.GetString("Main Screen", "FuelStation", "(none)")
    If MyFuelStationPing.Status = Net.NetworkInformation.IPStatus.Success Then
        Panel32.BackColor = Color.LightGreen
        Label226.Text = MyFuelStationPing.RoundtripTime & " ms"
    Else
        Panel32.BackColor = Color.LightSalmon
        Label222.Text = Label222.Text + 1
    End If

End Sub
```

What I want to do is have the screen load and function (rather than locking up until all pings finish) and update the buttons and labels as the pings replies come in. I'm not sure how to transfer the information about what button and labels to update with each ping when done asynchronously. Any advice would be great, also if there are suggestions on how to clean up this code by perhaps some kind of loop statement I'm open to that as well, I know my code is very simplistic and perhaps not done in the most efficient manner.

Thanks for any help you can provide.

Comment: Background workers or threads should be employed here

Comment: Sounds like it is time for you to learn how to use the [Async keyword](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh191564.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for the hint there Ghost. After reading your comment I researched the background worker and found a quick and easy solution to my problem and best of all it was really easy to implement. I simply created a backgroundworker in visual studio, had it run my 'pingallmills()' sub on it's dowork event and then called  BackgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync() on the form load event. Worked like a charm, the program no longer locks up and updates very well. I also had to add the Control.CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls = False line to form load or it wouldn't work properly. Thanks Again.

Comment: I should also mention that my program runs the pings every 5 seconds to update the screen, so i needed a way to prevent the background worker from starting again before it had finished the last run. So I created an allownextping boolean which was defaulted to false, then set to true on the Background worker's RunWorkerCompleted event. my timer checks the boolean using a simple if-then statement before it will recall the dowork event. I then reset to false when the dowork is activated again.

Comment: @HansPassant I am familiar with async pinging and I know how to implement it with a handler and all of that, the problem I was having is figuring out how each ping can update it's associated buttons and labels, I couldn't find any examples in my searches of how to carry that information through... but Ghost's post has pretty much solved my issue

Answer (score 0):

```
        IPAddress ip_addr1;
        IPAddress ip_addr2;
        IPAddress ip_addr3;

        // calling an asynchronous operations.
        var result1 = new System.Net.NetworkInformation.Ping().SendPingAsync(ip_addr1);
        var result2 = new System.Net.NetworkInformation.Ping().SendPingAsync(ip_addr2);
        var result3 = new System.Net.NetworkInformation.Ping().SendPingAsync(ip_addr3);

        // do another initialization stuff

        // check result
        if (result1.Result.Status == IPStatus.Success)
            Console.WriteLine("1: Sucess");
        else
            Console.WriteLine("1: Failure");

        if (result2.Result.Status == IPStatus.Success)
            Console.WriteLine("2: Sucess");
        else
            Console.WriteLine("2: Failure");
```

Or watch this solution:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/481080/Continuous-asynchronous-Ping-using-TAP-and-IProgre

Comment: This isn't quite what I was wanting, but your link to the codeproject item was quite interesting, thanks for posting that.